# Is it possible from a store listing to determine if an app is specific to a particular OEM/Operator?

Tags: store, compatibility

Some apps are exclusive to oems and/or mobile operators. Is there any way to see this on the marketplace listing? For example, I believe [sound enhancer](http://www.windowsphone.com/s?appId=2d37d956-51b1-df11-8a2f-00237de2db9e) is exclusive to HTC devices, but other than them being listed as the publisher, this doesn't seem to be shown anywhere? It doesn't seem to show any different to, say, the [local.angle app](http://windowsphone.com/s?appid=5ffa3ca9-07d3-480d-b5d1-a880f20e8c39) that I bought from my old phone and carried across OK (presumeably an open market app).

The closest I can see is that apps that were specific to my old phones show "This app is not available for all phones. Try downloading it on your phone." in the [Purchase History](https://www.windowsphone.com/en-gb/my/purchase-history), but this doesn't help me for apps on my current phone (for example, if I'm being asked for an app suggestion from a friend)

Comment: But I'm using both the App Folder by Samsung and Nokia.

Comment: @NK I'm not sure what you mean by that? Are you highlighting that some apps made by manufacturers are not specific to their devices, or something else?

Comment: I just meant applications like SysApp Pusher support exclusive applications from different OEM. There are region specific and hardware specific apps. I'm not sure about the OEM specific apps. May be it's there as Sound Enhancer you mentioned about.